# wanted to know about ~tilde operator?

Tags: c++, operators

I have seen many sites and referred books and reach to a point that tilde(~) operator is used to do ones' complement but when i ran the following code snippet ,i got amazed by its output.Can anybody explain me the output ??

The output  coming is **-11** for the following code.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x=10;
    cout<<~x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's [bitwise NOT](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). The output depends if negative `int`'s are implemented as 2 complement.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ,thats i know i am asking about its functioning in the above code.How -11 is coming as output????

Comment: @sagg1295: So? On a 2's complement platform, 1's complement of `10` is is indeed `-11`

Answer (score 2):

The tilde is a bitwise NOT operator, so what it does is invert bits. Since the int is signed, it uses 2's complement for negative numbers:

```
00001010 = 10
11110101 = -11
```

Comment: 2's complement of 10(00001010) is 11110110.u have written 1's complement of 10.then how -11 is coming as output i not able to understand tht

Comment: Follow up question - why is it only operating on the 1 byte?  (answer) it isn't, the rest of the bits are, which still on 2's compliment gives -11

Comment: It's operating on all the bytes, I just wrote the single byte since the others are kinda irrelevant in this scenario. And @sagg1295, I have written it right, invert the bits and add 1, you get 11.

Comment: @person66,sorry,i'm not able to understand the 2's complement of 10 ,my 2's complement is coming as 11110110 not  mentioned by you above.can u please explain me the 2's complement of 10.It will be very grateful.

Comment: @sagg1295 I don't think you understand how 2's complement works. 10 represented in 2's complement will still just be 10, because it's positive, so it doesn't change. To represent a negative number in 2's complement, say -11, you take positive 11, invert the bits, and add 1. There are plenty of resources online explaining how this works in more details, I'd suggest you read them if you're still confused.

Comment: I will also mention that if you did the above without adding 1 after inverting the bits, you would be doing 1's complement. The reason 2's complement is preferred is because it has only one '0' value. With 1's complement, there is both a 0, and a -0 (0 being all bits 0, -0 being all bits 1).

Answer (score 0):

The operator concerned here is the http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic Bitwise not operator, which is reversing all the bits of the number 10, to get the number -11, which is resulted from reversing the bits.